# How to properly store mushrooms

Tags: storage-method, mushrooms

I recently bought some mushrooms from the farmers market and have kept them in a brown paper bag on top of the fridge.  4 days later, they have started to have a slight odor between a mixture of dirt and dogs droppings.  I suspect I have stored the mushrooms improperly, so it begs the question:  What's the best way to store fresh mushrooms?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Mushrooms should be stored in the refrigerator in a breathable container. A paper bag works great. Mushrooms stored in this manner should last at least 4-5 days.

For the record, the top of the fridge is one of the worst places to store foods. Depending on the model it can actually be a few degrees higher than ambient temperature, thus accelerating spoilage.

Comment: Thanks for the response and additional fridge tip.  I guess I'll be chucking this batch of mushrooms out.

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not be applicable to your uses, but I quarter and then roast unseasoned mushrooms at 425 degrees Fahrenheit until they stop releasing water, then cool and repackage. They will remain good for much longer.

While I acknowledge this is really just a partial dehydration, I was taught dry sautéing years ago as a technique for flavor, so it’s something I do regardless.